# No verbose for Nu_SVR in scikit-learn

Tags: scikit-learn, svm, libsvm

I'm using SVM in scikit learn, and need to have verbose to see how my model is doing while training.
But i can't get the verbose in SVM and i keep getting the following output :*

```
 begin training ....
 [LibSVM]
```

this is the code i wrote :

```
print("begin training ....")
svm = NuSVR(kernel="rbf",C=20, nu=0.9,verbose=True)
svm.fit(trX,trY)
print(".... training ended")
```

so why i'm getting [LibSVM] instead of verbose? and what should i do to get a verbose ?

Comment: *libsvm* is the optimizer used internally. Read the docs, which give some warning about this feature (although it probably should work for this simple case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably using this in an Jupyter notebook or some other environment that redirects standard output (stdout) stream.

The fit method of NuSVR shoves the task to LibSVM which is written in C++ ([source here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b464d094d2c468a16ea9f8bf8d42d949f84/sklearn/svm/src/libsvm/svm.cpp)). The compiled C++ code writes informational messages to stdout. When `verbose=True` is set in NuSVR, it will attempt to grab those messages from stdout, but this won't necessarily work if some notebook environment stands in the way.

Testing the same in a normal Python console (or as normal as pythonanywhere.com is) produces a verbose message:

```
*
optimization finished, #iter = 260
epsilon = -0.000005
obj = -255.403240, rho = -1.521151
nSV = 30, nBSV = 12
[LibSVM]NuSVR(C=20, cache_size=200, coef0=0.0, degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='rbf',
   max_iter=-1, nu=0.9, shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=True)
```

LibSVM is not *very* verbose: it does not give step-by-step messages throughout its iterative process, unless something goes wrong with iteration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually yes i'm using jupyter notebook, and since the verbose of SVR shows up only at the end of training it won't help me a lot, so thanks for your answer.